# Win10 - Open RDP using Win-key + name of server

Tags: windows, remote, desktop

I need to RDP to many servers.
On Win7 i put all RDP links into the C:\Users\%user%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs folder, making it possible to press the "Windows key + name of server" - then it returned the RDP.

On Windows 10 the new Start Menu doesnt seem to work this way. I have tried to put RDP links into same dest. without luck.

What does work, is that I have a server called backupxx.domainname.something.
If I press Windows key + backup it returns several folders called backup, Word docs called backupstrategy etc. etc. - this is useless.

I dont want to use icons for clicking on or write the entire name of the server each time.
I am looking forward for your help.

Thank you.
Michael

Comment: You were doing something unsupported. It is not surprising that it no longer works at all.

Comment: I was doing something unssupported? How can being calling a program using the Start Menu's "Run" functionality be unsupported. If you press the Windows key on your keyboard, it will show and highlight the Run in Start menu. Type in what you need and it will return it. This is probadly the most basic functionality in Windows 7+ other than having a C: partition. Thanks for taking the time to answer though.